# How to apply selectOverlap property to week and day view but not to month view of fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using fullcalendar plugin and just wanted to ask how can I apply the `selectOverlap: false` property to week and day view but not to the month view.

For example if I change my view from week to month then `selectOverlap` should be true or otherwise if i change from month to any other view `selectOverlap` should be false but keep in mind i am not reloading the whole page.

This I want because if I have some data in month view and I try to select the month it should be selectable and here its not working because overlapping is considering for the whole month.

So I want that it should be selectable in month view and work as it is supposed to do in week and day view(Overlapping not possible).

I tried to add the view in local storage and putting the condition

```
selectOverlap: localStorage.getItem('viewName') === "month" ? true : false
```

so this is working for either the month view or week and day view but not both

```
selectOverlap: localStorage.getItem('viewName') === "month" ? true : false
```

Here this `localStorage.getItem('viewName')` gives the correct view name but since these properties applied only at the time of page load it is not possible for me to change in on changing the view, I want the `selectOverlap` property should be true for month view and false for rest of the view without reloading the page again and again.

Comment: I don't understand the use case here. If you want to prevent the user from selecting areas which are covered by existing events, then surely you would want to apply that rule no matter how or where the user is trying to make the selection? Why should the scale at which they view the calendar make any difference to the validation rule? Perhaps I have misunderstood. Can you give a concrete example of a situation, with some data and dates, where your suggestion would be useful?

Comment: Suppose I have event for today from 10 to 11 am which will be shown in all view.So for week and day view if I drag to select from 9 to 11 it should not be possible for me because I am already having event from 10 to 11  but in case of month view if i try to select the whole day it won't be possible because I am having some data.What I want is in month view I want to select data which will give the time interval from past 30 minutes to current time which I am doing with some jquery code.So this will not be overlapped with the event and thus i want to select in this view.

Comment: Ok. This arises because you're not using the month view as it's intended. If you want the user to select a specific time interval, then you should direct them to the agenda view. Month view is only intended as an overview, and you can only select days with it. If you've implemented some custom code to work around that, then you perhaps need some other custom code to validate the selection instead of trying to use selectOverlap.

Comment: However, if you really want to do this, there is a solution (as revealed by the documentation). I will add an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that

> since these properties applied only at the time of page load it is not
>   possible for me to change in on changing the view

This is true, but there's already a way to avoid this problem. As per the [documentation for selectOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap) you can provide a callback function instead of a fixed value. This will then be executed by fullCalendar every time an overlap occurs, and so it can evaluate the situation dynamically at that moment.

This way you can [ask fullCalendar what the current view is](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view) and make a decision based on that. For example:

```
selectOverlap: function(event) {
  return ($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name == "month");
}
```

This will return true whenever the view type is "month", thus allowing the overlap to proceed.

Comment: Yes it worked.I just changed the code little bit `selectOverlap: function(event) {
                    return ($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name === "month");
                },` **Thank you so much** for this help.It helped me alot

Comment: Ah ok that's because you are using fullCalendar version 3 not 4. You didn't tag it so I assumed the latest version. I've edited my answer. P.s. if the answer helped you then please remember to mark it as accepted - thanks!

Comment: Thanks @ADyson for your solution but I stuck in one more situation.Suppose the event is added for 10:15 to 11:15 then how can I add new event for 10 to 10:15 as this slot becomes **non selectable** because of `selectOverlap: false` as it is not allowing me to add event of this slot?Thanks in advance

Comment: @PrabhatKumar Sorry but why are you still using `selectOverlap: false`? As per the code in my answer you should have removed that fixed option and used the version I provided above with a callback function. That was the whole point - to make it so that the overlapping was only forbidden within the "month" view.

Comment: Ya actually I am using `selectOverlap: function(event) {
  return ($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name == "month");
}` this only but my point is not related to view now because it is working as expected in different view type.But now the question is how can I add event for the slot which is partially filled with some other event .As it is not selectable

Comment: Ok I understand now. How long is your slot duration? If you don't set a value then it defaults to 30 minutes. If you need the kind of flexibility you described then reduce the duration of the slots so that the 10:00 to 10:15 period is treated as a separate slot. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3jLrytvp/

Comment: I want the default slotDuration and also I want it in a generic way.Suppose I added entry of 10 to 10:20 then how can I add for those 10 minutes(10:20 to 10:30 the slotDuration is default) if it is non selectable.I don't want to set some fix slot duration.

Comment: you always have to set a fixed slot duration, you can't escape that. (The default duration is also a fixed duration, so you can't state "I want the default duration" and also state "I don't want a fix slot duration" - that's a contradiction.) The only thing you can do to help with your requirement is to set a smaller duration as I suggested. There is no other alternative. Maybe you need it as small as 5 minutes or even 1 minute - I don't know whether people are allowed to set any start time they like for events, or it must be aligned to the nearest 5 minutes or something?

Comment: E.g. this demo would overcome the 10:00 to 10:20 and 10:20 - 10:30 problem you discussed in your last comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sv3dzL9b/2/ . Reduce the slot duration to 5 minutes and it's even more flexible: http://jsfiddle.net/sv3dzL9b/3/ (I used `slotLabelInterval` as well to reduce the number of time labels cluttering up the view.)